# file not found error with call ftp delete function in utf8 file name

Tags: delphi, iis-7, ftp, windows-server-2008-r2, indy

i connected to ftp server with `idftp` in `delphi7`. when i get file list from ftp server the utf8 file names was weird`(for example ی => ؟ and پ => _)`.
i used command `opts utf8 on` and server response 200 and use `showmessage(utf8decode(filename))` it return correct `utf8` file names.

```
now my problem is that:
```

i want to call `delete` ftp function for delete `utf8` file names but server response file not found. i have same problem for downloading(get) `utf8` file names from windows server with `windows 2008R2` and `IIS7`.

Comment: Which version of Indy are you using?

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau i use indy 9

Comment: Indy 9 does not natively support Unicode at all, thus does not know anything about UTF-8. `AnsiString` values are transmitted as-is as raw data. In Delphi 7, `UTF8Encode()` takes a `WideString` as input and returns a UTF8 encoded `AnsiString` as output, and `UTF8Decode()` takes a UTF8 encoded `AnsiString` as input and returns a `WideString` as output. Make sure you are actually passing real UTF-8 data to `TIdFTP.Delete()` after enabling UTF-8 on the server, and that you are not losing any Unicode characters during UTF8->WideString->AnsiString->WideString->UTF8 round trip data conversions.

Comment: WideString->AnsiString and AnsiString->WideString conversions can lose and/or alter character data if you are not careful with them.